# Loading F# module in FSI

Tags: f#

I have a fsx file that I use for interactive development of my project. It preloads all the dlls plus I want to mock a couple of functions that should behave differently in FSI world.

In fsx I have this code:

```
// #r needed dlls
open FSharp.Charting

module InteractiveUtil =
    let plotMe (c : ChartTypes.GenericChart) = c.ShowChart() |> ignore
    let logMe (c : string) = c |> printfn "%s"
```

Now in .fs files I want to play with I have this:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#load "LiveInvestigationPreload.fsx"
open InteractiveUtil
#endif
```

But when I try to execute snippet above I get

> error FS0039: The namespace or module 'InteractiveUtil' is not defined

I also noticed that definition of InteractiveUtil module looks like this:

```
namespace FSI_0009
  module InteractiveUtil = begin
    val plotMe : c:FSharp.Charting.ChartTypes.GenericChart -> unit
    val logMe : c:string -> unit
  end
```

So FSI_0009 is something fsi created for me.

Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it. When I put top level module in the beginning of fsx it worked.

```
module InteractiveUtil

#time
#r ...
open FSharp.Charting

let plotMe (c : ChartTypes.GenericChart) = c.ShowChart() |> ignore
let logMe (c : string) = c |> printfn "%s"
```

I would have deleted the question but since I already got one vote up it seems like someone else is interested in solution.